# Переписать на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const todo = document.getElementById("todo-list");
let task;
while (task = prompt("Введите пункт списка:"))
  todo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<li>${task}</li>`);
```

```html
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: .......а зачем?

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю в чём тут сложность была.

```js
const $todo = $('#todo-list');
let task;
while (task = prompt("Введите пункт списка:"))
  $todo.append(`<li>${task}</li>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
```